# Difference between String.Sort and Greater Than/Less Than Operators VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, sorting, string-comparison

I have a simple routine to find the next object based on a name property in an un-ordered collection of objects. I go through the collection and collect all the names in a `List(of String)` adding any names that are `>` my current name, which should give a list of everything that comes after the current key. I then sort the list using the default `.Sort()` method on the `List(of String)` and  take the first item in the list, which should be my next item. I do the reverse to find the previous item, add all items `<` my current name, sort, and take the last item in the list.

However, this method skips over some items. For example I have items named 1210, 1210-ADA, and 1210_ADA_DB. Using this method, getting the next item skips the middle item 1210-ADA and finds 1210_ADA_DB, but finding the previous item seems to work.

If my process is correct, my only explanation is that the `<` and `>` operators compare differently than the `.Sort()` method. Is this true? What are the differences?

Code for finding next item:

```
        Dim Key As String = Name
        Dim NameList As New List(Of String)
        For Each obj As T In Collection
            Dim ObjKey As String = Obj.Key
            If  ObjKey > Key Then
                NameList.Add(ObjKey)
            End If
        Next
        If NameList.Count = 0 Then Return Nothing
        NameList.Sort()
        Dim NextKey As String = NameList.First
```

Comment: Rather than *describing* your code, why don't you *post* your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already found what the problem might be.  But to annotate, you are getting bitten by some VB6 compat behavior.  The default for Option Compare is Binary which uses String.CompareOrdinal().  Not what List.Sort() uses.  Option Compare Text uses CultureInfo.CompareInfo.Compare() with the CompareOptions.IgnoreWidth,  CompareOptions.IgnoreKanaType, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase options.  Also not what List.Sort() uses.

Avoid the operators and use String.Compare() instead.

Answer (score 1):

> my only explanation is that the < and > operators compare differently than the .Sort() method. Is this true?

No. `Sort` internally uses the [`String.IComparable(Of String).CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w.aspx) method which yields results consistent with `<` and `>`.

However, this is only true as long as you have not changed the [`Option Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t3khw5f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for the project or the current file. This will change the behaviour of `<` and `>` but not of the above-mentioned method.

Comment: I have not changed Options Compare. According to my project settings Option Compare is set to binary, which I would assume is the default.

Comment: You've led me to my answer, but < and > apparently are still different from String.CompartTo, documentation for `CompareTo` says  `This method performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) comparison using the current culture. ` and `Option Compart Text` says `bases string comparisons on a case-insensitive, textual sort order determined by your application's locale.`

Comment: @Kratz What you’ve cited counts only for `Option Compare Text`. Under `Option Compare Binary` they behave identical (case-sensitive, culture-sensitive).

Comment: `Option Compare Binary bases string comparisons on a sort order derived from the internal binary representations of the characters.`, plus now that I know my project is set for `binary`, the behavior of my code proves they are different. In my example `-` was comparing differently from `_`.  I replaced the `>` with String.Compare (so it compares the same way) and it is working good now.